# Why must i declare variable?

Tags: c#, sql

I got an error:

> Must declare scalar variable '@20'

...when loading a webpage to fetch query data.

I've done a few web inquiries but i don't understand why a variable needs to be *declared*.

This started, when I had written out the code and loaded the page, it worked fine. Made a few modifications to unrelated parts of the page, refreshed again and started getting an error. I've never had to deal with *declare* before.

```
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM business_Customer WHERE memberid=@20";

var memberid = Database.Open("StarterSite").QueryValue("SELECT memberid FROM business_Customer WHERE email=@0",WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
```

That's the script at the top of my page, right before the html loads.

```
foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString, memberid)) {...}
```

...is the script that is giving me the error.

But before modifying and adding to the page, the `memberid` variable worked just fine. The value is an integer, and i used it separately, by itself to confirm that it works. I tried changing the snippet to `foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString, (int) memberid)) {...}` and it gave me an error that said:

> Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type

I'm extremely confused... What does declaring have to do with calling a value from an sql database? Is there a simple solution to my problem? i read other stackoverflow posts related to this, but the solutions were written in SQL syntax, and used "Declare", there wasnt enough resources for me to understand how to apply their solution to my problem.

---

I discovered what was wrong with my script. It was missing an external javascript file, needed for another set of values, that somehow had something to do with error. But... my original for my original question, is declaring a variable something i *need* to know? I dont mind studying it (if there were resources that went into details on what it's for, or when it's used), but i've never had to deal with it before... is it something "important/valuable"?

Comment: Because a *SQL variable* must have a value if used in query.. in this case that is caused because a parameter named `@20` was not bound. Perhaps it was supposed to be `memberid=@0` (meaning the first parameter, from the C# 'memberid' variable, bound)? (Do notice how the other query uses `@0` and not `@20`: patterns matter.)

Comment: Originally, i had it set for 0, but the error came up '@0', after searching around on internet, i realized that the variable could be anything. So i gave it a random number to see if it could point to where the error was coming from. The only thing i understand is `selectQueryString` is the cause of my error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `@0` - this represents the first argument.

`Query` and `QueryValue` both take 2 parameters - a commandText and an array of parameters. To specify where the parameters go in your commandtext, you use `@0`, `@1`, etc.

For example:

```
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM business_Customer WHERE memberid=@0";
db.Query(selectQueryString, memberid)
```

So when you call `Query`, it will replace `@0` with the value of the `memberid` variable.

Comment: The `@0` and `@1` was the first thing i tried, and that's why i started playing with the `@20`, cause i wasnt too sure which variable was the issue. I know that the error is coming from `selectQueryString` but... i'm not sure why. i thought maybe i should rewrite `Query` to not include a 2nd db query, but one is a value, and the other is a string... do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I suspect you are seeing the second error because memberid is null.

Comment: that's what i thought too. But i loaded the variable, `memberid` on a separate page without any of the code snippets, it gave me the value i wanted. It worked the first time, before i started adding more coding to the page. But with the error not making any sense, i'm not sure what what/where i went wrong...